# how to ignore a string that is not a number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const liArray = ["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "10 hi", "56 hello"];
const parentElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

const getNumbers = liArray.map((i) => Number(i.substr(0,i.indexOf(' '))));
const getWords = liArray.map((i) => i.substr(i.indexOf(' ')+1));

const min = Math.min.apply(Math, getNumbers);
const max = Math.max.apply(Math, getNumbers);

getNumbers.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
  const elm = document.createElement('p');
  let text = `${index + 1}. ${(currentValue == min || currentValue == max) ?
 `(${currentValue})` : currentValue} ${getWords[index]}`;
  elm.innerText = text;
  parentElement.appendChild(elm);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

This code that will create a `p` element for every index in an array and it will put a parantheses on the lowest and highest number in an array, so output of this code will be

```
1. 5.6 hello
2. 8.7 hi
3. (1.3) hey
4. 10 hi
5. (56) hello
```

the problem is when i have a string like this `"ABC(1)"` in the array, it will output `NaN`  because this code `const getNumbers = liArray.map((i) => Number(i.substr(0,i.indexOf(' '))));` gets the characters before the first white space and turns them into a number and  `"ABC(1)"` isnt a number

so i want to ignore that string when its calculating the highest and lowest number and putting parantheses  and when its converting the characters before the first white space into a number

so if my array is like this `["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "DEF(2)", "56 hello"]` i expect it to output

```
1. 5.6 hello
2. 8.7 hi
3. (1.3) hey
4. DEF(2)
5. (56) hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to identify the numbers you want instead - capture both the initial digits at the beginning of the string, followed by a space, followed by whatever comes afterwards. If this pattern matches, you'll know the line is of the format you want. With both the number and the words that follow captured, put it into a single structure, maybe call it a component. After finding the min and max values in the components, iterate through the components again, inserting the values while checking whether the number being iterated over is a minimum or maximum.

```js
const inputs = ["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "DEF(2)", "56 hello", "DEF(4) A3 D"];

const components = inputs.map(str => {
  const match = str.match(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (.+)/);
  return match
    ? [Number(match[1]), match[2]]
    : null;
});
const numbersWithoutNull = components
  .filter(n => n !== null)
  .map(c => c[0]);
const min = Math.min(...numbersWithoutNull);
const max = Math.max(...numbersWithoutNull);

const container = document.getElementById("myDiv");
components.forEach((component, index) => {
  const p = container.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
  const [num, word] = component || [];
  const record = num === min || num === max;
  const textOnRight = component === null
    ? inputs[index]
    : `${record ? '(' : ''}${num}${record ? ')' : ''} ${word}`;
  p.textContent = `${index + 1}. ${textOnRight}`;
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: hi i have another question here, the problem is if i have a string like this `"DEF(4) A3 D"` it doesnt ignore that string and returns `"3 D"` but i want that string to be ignored and still return the same string because the characters before the first whitespace which is `DEF(4)` isnt a number

Comment: You can add `^` to the beginning of the regular expression to ensure it matches starting at the beginning of the string.